# Cannot find module 'coffee-script'

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, towerjs

Trying to get a basic site set up with TowerJS as a test, but ran into this error when running the scaffold generator.

```
Macbook:app john$ tower generate scaffold Post title:string body:text belongsTo:user
{ [Error: Cannot find module 'coffee-script'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/john/Sites/tower/app/app/config/shared/application'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Function.Tower.Application.Application.reopenClass.instance (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tower/lib/tower-application/server/application.js:42:15)
    at _.extend.namespace (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tower/lib/tower-support/shared/shared.js:218:30)
    at GeneratorScaffoldGenerator.Tower.GeneratorResources.buildApp (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tower/lib/tower-generator/server/resources.js:273:66)
    at GeneratorScaffoldGenerator.Generator (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tower/lib/tower-generator/server/generator.js:57:23)
    at new GeneratorScaffoldGenerator (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tower/lib/tower-generator/server/generators/tower/scaffold/scaffoldGenerator.js:21:61)
    at Function.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tower/lib/tower-generator/server/generator.js:22:12)
```

Comment: Is coffee script installed (globally) on your box? What does "npm list -g coffee-script" returns? If it returns "empty" try installing it first with "npm install -g coffee-script"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Update your package.json file

```
"coffee-script": "~1.6.3"
```

on "devDependencies" and update the npm again

```
npm update
```

the same issue fixed for me

Answer (score 58):

Had similar problem when using grunt, I've removed

```
node_modules
```

folder from my root folder and run

```
npm install
```

That fixed my problem

Comment: +1. I really wish this didn't work for me, but it did.

Comment: It worked because npm does not do transactional installs. When something goes wrong with an npm installation (I had git issues) npm will often create the directory and the package.json for packages that are not fully/properly installed and does not have any flag for marking a position in the tree as fully installed so it can't, and doesn't, automatically repair botched installs.

Answer (score 10):

You need to check NODE_PATH variable against the location given by `npm list -g coffee-script`.
If empty, `npm install -g coffee-script`.

Answer (score 8):

This did the trick for me

```
npm install --save-dev coffee-script
```

using node v0.10.31

Comment: This loads coffee-script into devDependencies of package.json. Fixed the problem for me, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check NODE_PATH variable and if it is empty then set it with instructions given here
http://www.davidarno.org/2012/02/09/writing-a-node.js-module-in-coffeescript/

Answer (score 3):

This is a question from 2012. Now it's nearly 2015, and in the meantime, there is now another, new approach for a differerent variation of the problem caused by breaking changes introduced into node and coffeescript.

For coffeescript > v1.7 you must now call

```
var coffee = require('coffee-script').register();
```

instead of

```
var coffee = require('coffee-script');
```

See this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21585379
to this question: 
[How to properly set up Coffeescript with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583899/how-to-properly-set-up-coffeescript-with-node-js)

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/fgnass/node-dev#settings
Note: If you want to use coffee-script < 1.7 you have to change the setting to {"coffee": "coffee-script"}.

so update your coffe-script or config your setting

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the required packages separately like:

```
npm install coffee-script
```

after that it required one more package and hopefully it was the last one :D

Answer (score 0):

With 2 simple steps, I was able to fix this issue

1. `npm cache clean`
2. `npm install`

Hope this helps!