# Node.js not recognizing Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, sails.js

I am currently trying to get into NodeJS together with the SailsJS framework.
And I want to use coffeescript on the serverside aswell, but after converting all files in `config/*.js` to `config/*.coffee` properly with js2coffee, I get the following error when trying to start up the app:

**config/400.coffee**

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

pointing to the first character in the file, which is a hashtag for a coffee comment. So it seems the app does not recognize the file as coffeescript, but searching for standard js instead.

I tried installing the package `coffee-script` and requireing it in

**app.js**

```
require('coffee-script');
require('sails').lift(require('optimist').argv);
```

but it doesn't help.

If I delete `400.coffee`, the error appears in the next file `403.coffee` etc.

What am I doing wrong? Isn't coffeescript allowed in the config files or am I missing something?

Comment: How are you calling it from the command line?

Comment: @Bergi I am starting up with `sails lift`

Comment: I fear `require('coffee-script')` doesn't do what you want. Usually you'd need to compile the coffeescript explicitly to js before executing it with `node`, or use `coffee` to start it up. With sails however [it looks like you need some special flags to the executable](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/pull/1118).

Comment: If you are using the current stable coffeescript, I believe you need `require('coffee-script/register')`?

Comment: @loganfsmyth `require('coffee-script')` to `require('coffee-script/register')` works. Will I run into any problems if I inject it in `app.js`, e.g. performance wise?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to properly set up Coffeescript with Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583899/how-to-properly-set-up-coffeescript-with-node-js)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coffeescript 1.7.0, released Jan 28th, 2014, changed the `require('coffee-script')` behavior to only load the compiler itself. Now, do load the automatic compiler for `.coffee` files, you must call `require('coffee-script/register')` before loading any coffeescript files.

Keep in mind that using this will mean that every `.coffee` file will be recompiled every time you start `node`, which could increase startup times. That may or may not be important to you though.

Comment: I had to change the line in `sails.js` in the sails node module aswell, otherwise the server starts up but other sails commands end up in the same error. Sails itself does n ot seem to be updated for the newer coffee versions.

Comment: If you want to avoid the recompiling issue you mention in the second paragraph, check out [coffee-cache](https://www.npmjs.org/package/coffee-cache).